# i586-poky-linux: No rule to make target `arch/x86/tools/relocs.c', needed by `arch/x86/tools/relocs'

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I have Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit MAC running on VirtualBox on a Macbook Pro. I have the following in `hello_kernel.c` which I want to run.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>   

static int __init enter(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello Kernel Galileo\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Bye kernel Galileo\n");
    return;
}

module_init(enter);
module_exit(exit);
```

I have installed i586-poky-linux in `/home/esp/SDK/i586-poky-linux` and here is my `Makefile`.

```
obj-m:= hello_kernel.o

ARCH=x86
CROSS_COMPILE=i586-poky-linux-

all:
    make -C /home/esp/SDK/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -fr *.o
    rm -fr *.ko
    rm -fr *.mod.c
    rm -fr *.order
    rm -fr *.symvers
```

I get the following error when I run `sudo make`.

```
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `arch/x86/tools/relocs.c', needed by `arch/x86/tools/relocs'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/esp/SDK/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel'
```

I do not see `relocs` and `relocs.c` in `~/SDK/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel/arch/x86/tools/`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution! There were some scripts missing from my installation of i586-poky-linux kernel. To generate those scripts run `sudo make scripts` in `SDK/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/src/kernel`. This will generate the required scripts and everything just works fine. :)